# Horizontal AND Vertical Slider (Image Gallery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I need to create a slider gallery, where the I can slide the images horizontally and vertically. Like this:

http://o7.no/TVvsjj

Click left to move to the previous image, click down to view corresponding images to the current image, click right to move to the next image.

Anyone an idea where I can find a slider with this functionallity? Or which slider is predestinated to achieve this?

Thank you very much!

Greetings
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Try [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox). Check out the demos.